# Tabulator - rowContextMenu - HowTo get which cell the mouse-rightclick is performed

Tags: tabulator

Is it possible to get which cell the right-click context menu is performed with rowContextMenu?
rowContextMenu gives the data for all cells in the row, but I have not found how to get which cell the action happens.

Using contextMenu could be an option, but I want to build the columns-setup serverside as json and load the columns with

```
table.setColumns(columnsJson)
```

Setting columns contextmenu as a function is not a valid json,

```
columns": [
    { "title": "", "field": "age", "sorter": "string", "headerSort": false, "contextMenu": cellContextMenu}
]
```

And setting the "contextMenu" as a "string" fails with: error: "Uncaught TypeError: o.forEach is not a function"

```
columns": [
    { "title": "", "field": "age", "sorter": "string", "headerSort": false, "contextMenu": "cellContextMenu"}
]
```

Any tips on getting which cell the menu is trigged with rowContextMenu?
Or is there maybe a different/better solution builtin in Tabulator?

Reason for building the column setup serverside is that I want to have different context menu based on type of cell-data, and it will vary based on selection by user.

BR
Bjorn

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the cell that is being clicked on then you need to use the [Cell Context Menu](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/menu#cell-context) instead as this is passed the cell component that has been clicked.

You would then need to assign the menu per cell but this is easy if you define it as an array outside the table and then reference it on each column definition using the ***contextMenu*** property:

```js
//define cell context menu
var cellContextMenu = [
    {
        label:"Reset Value",
        action:function(e, cell){
            cell.setValue("");
        }
    },
]

//add header menu in column definition
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name",contextMenu:cellContextMenu}, 
        {title:"Age", field:"age",contextMenu:cellContextMenu}, 
        {title:"Address", field:"address",contextMenu:cellContextMenu}, 
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you,
This is what i suspected, the need to use 'contextMenu' per column.
The 'problem' is that I want(hoped) to build the column setup serverside as a json-file, and then load it with table.setColumns(columnsJson).
//"Simplefied code"
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
columns:[] 
});
columnsJson = fetchColumnsJSON()
table.setColumns(columnsJson)
table.redraw(true)
This works for adding columns that do not reference a function or a var, as contextMenu will do. Adding columns with table.setColumns with a json with reference to "var" or "function" is not working.-Bjorn

Comment: Will look at bulding the table columns directly server side instead of loading as json.
Thank you. - BR Bjorn